# How to make To list invisible to the recipients? (in Gmail)

Tags: gmail

Right now I go with copying all email contacts in BCC and write my own email address in To column ... that's what I could come up after a lot of searching in Google.

But, it shows my name in recipient list to my recipient.

I don't want to display that either.

Comment: Have you tried leaving the To: field blank ?

Comment: Your address is already in the From: field, so what difference does it make?

Comment: @phwd, I tried, but it gives error, saying TO field cannot be blank.

Comment: @Al Everett, I want to hide the recipient list from the recipients.. I don't want them to know whom and all I am sending the mail, kind of privacy/security etc.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If leaving the To: field blank doesn't work, you could add something such as:

> user@example.com

to the To: field.

http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Example.com

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

As long as GMail allows you to leave the "To:" field blank you should be able to send the mail just by filling in the "BCC:" list.

Answer (score 0):

When sending an email in Google, the "CC" field stands for carbon copy, and "BCC" stands for blind carbon copy, meaning that the recipients are "blind" to the other email addresses.

You do not need to enter an email in the "To" or "CC" fields.  When your message arrives, your recipients will be able to see that the email was sent to their inbox, in addition to "undisclosed recipients." They will not be able to view the other email addresses, nor will they be able to "reply all."